# The job has been attempted too many times or run too long

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.7, laravel-queue

I have an issue with the Job dispatching in Laravel 5.7. 
I need to pull the customer's data in a job, but every time I'm running it on the prod server, I got

```
[2020-01-02 13:02:02] production.INFO: Job started  
[2020-01-02 13:02:02] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:02:02] production.INFO: Contest: name
[2020-01-02 13:02:02] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:12:08] production.INFO: Job started  
[2020-01-02 13:12:08] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:12:08] production.INFO: Contest: name
[2020-01-02 13:12:08] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:22:15] production.INFO: Job started  
[2020-01-02 13:22:15] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:22:15] production.INFO: Contest: name
[2020-01-02 13:22:15] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:32:21] production.INFO: Job started  
[2020-01-02 13:32:21] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:32:21] production.INFO: Contest: name
[2020-01-02 13:32:21] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:42:28] production.INFO: Job started  
[2020-01-02 13:42:28] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:42:28] production.INFO: Contest: name 
[2020-01-02 13:42:28] production.INFO: ===================  
[2020-01-02 13:44:33] production.ERROR: App\Jobs\SendContestMailToFans has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): App\\Jobs\\SendContestMailToFans has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. at /home/forge/loycals.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:401)
[stacktrace]
```

Here is a Job body. As I can see from the log the job stops at pulling recipients.

```
private function sendContestEmails()
{
    Log::info('Job started');

    $contest = $this->contest->load([
        'prizes',
        'primary_sponsor',
        'secondary_sponsors',
    ]);

    Log::info('===================');
    Log::info('Contest: ' . $contest->title);
    Log::info('===================');

    $recipients = $contest->primary_sponsor->first()->subscribers()->whereDate('email_sent_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->orWhereNull('email_sent_at')->get(); // list of subscribers (which is a unique list of fans for that sponsor)

    $count = 1;
    foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
        $count++;
    }
    Log::info('===================');
    Log::info('Recipients: ' . $count);
    Log::info('===================');


    $sponsor = $contest->primary_sponsor->first();
    $subject = 'New Contest at ' . $sponsor->title; // venue title

    Log::info('===================');
    Log::info('Sponsor: ' . $sponsor->title);
    Log::info('===================');

    Log::info('Job finished');
}
```

Here is a worker setup on Forge:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3blcv.jpg

I also set the 'retry_after' to be 600 in config/queue.php. I tried to run the job with the timeout 0 and with a default 'retry_after' but got the same error. I tried to do it on the staging server with the same configurations and dummy data in the database and the job has been finished in a few seconds.

Comment: You're never getting to the recipients echo, so something is going on with the query, most likely. You'll have to try it specifically to figure out why it's taking so long. Side note, since $recipients will be a Laravel collection, you can use `$count = $recipients->count();` to get the total instead of using the foreach loop.

Comment: @aynber yeah, for some reason when I swap NotNull and WhereDate so the NotNull become the first condition, it worked! Which is weird, because on my local machine as well as on staging server the old queue was working fine.
Thank you!

Comment: You could try adding ->toSql() at the end of the query and dump the result to inspect what is going on in the two scenarios (when whereDate is first vs. when whereDate is last).

Comment: First, this part  <code>$recipients = $contest->primary_sponsor->first()->subscribers()->whereDate('email_sent_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->orWhereNull('email_sent_at')->get();</code>

You stop here. In the Log you don't have Recipients: $count.
Add it in try{}catch{} block to check for errors.

Comment: First, this part  [code]$recipients = $contest->primary_sponsor->first()->subscribers()->whereDate('email_sent_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->orWhereNull('email_sent_at')->get();[code]

You stop here. In the Log you don't have Recipients: $count.

Add it in try{}catch{} block to check for errors.
Check for is_null($recipients).
Try to start new worker for each sponsor subscribers.
Try to use $recipients->count();
Check for is_null($recipient->email); You want to sent email, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

change 'retry_after' option in config/queue.php.
you should set the 'retry_after' value to the maximum number of seconds your jobs should reasonably take to complete processing.

```
'retry_after' => 1080
```